# Python Better Way to Express This Recursive Function

Tags: python, recursion

Python version 2.7.6

I wrote an iterative function that computes the number of trailing zeros expected with a particular factorial. I then tried to rewrite it as a recursive function.
This is the recursive result:

```
def f_FactorialTailZeros(v_Num, v_Result = 0):
    if v_Num < 5:
        return v_Num
    v_Result = v_Result + f_FactorialTailZeros(v_Num // 5, v_Num // 5)
    return v_Result

print(f_FactorialTailZeros(30)) ## 7
print(f_FactorialTailZeros(70)) ## 16
```

It works, but, for the sake of learning, is there a better way?

Comment: Do you mean to return 0 for values less than 5?

Comment: I don't see any problem at all with the way you have defined the recursive function. Offtopic: the prefix notation is something to avoid nowadays.

Comment: // , Ikaros, can you provide any further reading on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
def f_FactorialTailZeros(v_Num):
    if v_Num < 5:
        return 0
    return v_Num // 5 + f_FactorialTailZeros(v_Num // 5)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the ticket. And I see where I went off track as well, which is the most important thing. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think this is optimal. The beauty of recursion lies in the fact that you shouldn't need to keep track of state. Plus, passing in duplicate parameters to a function should also raise a red flag.
Good job OP for coming up with the recursive solution though! It's pretty neat and not immediately obvious until you see it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with recursive function have a look at following code and FYI read [this](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/factzero.htm)

```
def recursive_trailingZeroes(A):
    if A==0:
        return 0
    return (A//5)+recursive_trailingZeroes(A//5)
```

Comment: SO already finished the iterative method he wants to do it in recursive way

Comment: Thanks, however, I have an iterative version that works. I wanted to know if there were a better recursive version than the one that I wrote.